# Performing spline on 3D array

Tags: python, matlab, interpolation

I have been using Python recently for certain porting of internal company tools from MATLAB to Python.

I was able to succesfully port most of it but stuck in a particular point. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

In MATLAB, there is a cubic interpolation taking place which reads as following:
`z =spline(a,b,c)`
where a= 1x100 array, b= 2x2x100 array and c =1x200 array.

So, basically it is trying to interpolate existing 2x2 data of 100 points ( contained in b) into 200 points ( which is in c)

MATLAB is able to smoothly perform the operation with the resultant z being a 2x2x200 array.

How do i achieve the same in Python since im unable to find a equivalent spline function which deals with 3D arrays ( i only found the 1D array based Cubic interpolation but these will not be useful for my usecase)

Any help would be appreciated since im not deeply knowledgable on interpolation techniques to be able to derieve a custom method in Python myself.

***Edited on Nov 15:***

Thank you for your comments. Since it is a company internal code, im unable to reproduce the same here. However, i am putting out a sample of what im trying to achieve below:

Matlab Code:

```
data1=zeros(2,2,5)
set1=zeros(1,5)
set2=zeros(1,10)

 data1(1,1,1)=10
 data1(1,2,1)=11
 data1(2,1,1)=12
 data1(2,2,1)=13
% 
 data1(1,1,2)=10
 data1(1,2,2)=11
 data1(2,1,2)=12
 data1(2,2,2)=13
% 
 data1(1,1,3)=10
 data1(1,2,3)=11
 data1(2,1,3)=12
 data1(2,2,3)=13
% 
 data1(1,1,4)=10
 data1(1,2,4)=11
 data1(2,1,4)=12
 data1(2,2,4)=13

 data1(1,1,5)=10
 data1(1,2,5)=11
 data1(2,1,5)=12
 data1(2,2,5)=13



set1(1,:)=[2,4,6,8,10]
set2(1,:)=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

out=spline(set1,data1,set2)
```

This displays the result as expected where  data1 is a  2x2x5 array with set1 having  1x5 values which has to be interpolated into a set2 having 1x10 values.
The resultant interpolated data, out, is a 2x2x10 array.

```
>> size(data1)
ans =
     2     2     5
>> size(out)
ans =
     2     2    10
```

However, im unable to replicate the same behaviour is Python for a 3D array ( 1D arrays are fine with Univariate spline functions or similar ones).

The Python equivalent code for above is:

```
#!/user/bin/python

import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

data=np.zeros((2,2,5))
set1=[2,4,6,8,10]
set2=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for i in range(0,5):
 data[0,0,i]=10
 data[0,1,i]=11
 data[1,0,i]=12
 data[1,1,i]=13

print data.shape
print data[:,:,1]
print set1
print set2

out1=np.interp(set1,data,set2)
out2=griddata(set1,data,set2,method="cubic")
```

However, the errors i get for trying to run the np.interp or griddata are:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    line 22, in <module>
    out=griddata(set1,data,set2,method="cubic")
  File "/user/Python-2.6.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/ndgriddata.py", line 176, in griddata
    fill_value=fill_value)
  File "/user/Python-2.6.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 274, in __init__
    self._spline = splmake(x,oriented_y,order=order)
  File "/user/Python-2.6.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 771, in splmake
    coefs = func(xk, yk, order, conds, B)
  File "/user/Python-2.6.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 506, in _find_smoothest
    return _dot0(tmp, yk)
  File "/user/Python-2.6.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 480, in _dot0
    return dot(a, b.transpose(axes))
ValueError: objects are not aligned
```

and

```
File "/user/Python_scripts/ECPS_functions_definitions.py", line 958, in trise_check
    out2=np.interp(set1,data,set2)
  File "/user/Python-2.6.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1053, in interp
    return compiled_interp(x, xp, fp, left, right)
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

Any function which is able to replicate the spline of MATLAB for a 3D array would be helpful to me to move ahead with the code ( since this interpolation is not the main functionality of the code and the large code ahead is held up due to this function not working)

Comment: Try this one [scipy.interpolate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html)

Comment: How about adding example matlab data, actual calling code example, result printouts to your question - maybe just 10-20  length data sets?    And there are some SE results when searching on python, matlab and spline, interpolate in various combos